# iOS 13, Custom Image, title and subtitle in the presented UIActivityViewController

Tags: swift, ios13, uiactivityviewcontroller

I would like to know if there is any way to customise the image, title and subtitle of presented UIActivityViewController in iOS 13?

[image]

Comment: Did you figure this out? I've seen a few apps do and this I was wondering how they did it.

Comment: @ian yes i did, I will answer to this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found a solution using `UIActivityItemSource`

`UIActivityItemSource` have this protocol `activityViewControllerLinkMetadata(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> LPLinkMetadata?`which we can use to set image title and subtitle for our `UIActivityViewController`

This is an example:

```
 public func activityViewControllerLinkMetadata(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> LPLinkMetadata? {
    let metadata = LPLinkMetadata()

    metadata.title = "My title" // Preview Title

    // Set image 

        metadata.imageProvider = NSItemProvider(object: image)
        metadata.iconProvider = NSItemProvider(object: image)
        metadata.url = urlImage

   // Set URL for sharing 
        metadata.originalURL = myUrl // Add this if you want to have a url in your share message.

    return metadata
}
```

And this is the result: I have my custom image and title.

[image]

Comment: FYI You can kinda 'hack' the subtitle by using a file URL.  `metadata.originalURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "My custom subtitle")`

Comment: Unfortunately LPLinkMetadata is only available for iOS 13+

Comment: What object do you pass for image? For me the image is seen with extra white spaces around.

Comment: @SayaleePote It's a simple `UIImage` and it's working fine,

Comment: Thanks. I figured the issue I was facing. Do you have any idea why we cannot see - 'Add to Reading list' option even when we are sharing a link through the app? Struggling to find what is the issue.

Comment: @SayaleePote What was the issue that you figured out? I'm getting white space around my image as well… Thanks!

Comment: @SayaleePote facing same issue. Could you share a fix?

Comment: @ArtemZaytsev I don't remember the exact fix but make sure your image is a simple UIImage object that is assigned to  'let image = UIImage(named: "test")'

Comment: Does it work in iOS Simulator?, for some reason I don't see thumb image despite setting it.

Comment: For a full version of this solution: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/687916